# Loading image onclick event

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, events, jquery-events

How I load the images on web page on `onclick` event without reloading the whole page?

Here is my code:

```
<style type="text/css">
    div{
        border:1px solid red;
        margin-left: 12%;
        width: 20%;
        height: 200px;
        display: inline-block;
    }   
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function changepic () {
        
    }
</script>
<html>
  <body>
     <div onclick="changepic">
     </div>
     <div onclick="changepic">
     </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I want to place the image in div when the client click one of them div element.

Comment: do you change the curent div replace the image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```js
function changepic(div) {
 document.getElementById(div).src = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/1b/Square_200x200.png";
}
```

```css
div{
  border:1px solid red;
  margin-left: 12%;
  width: 20%;
  height: 200px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div onclick="changepic('div1')">
  <img id="div1" />
</div>
<div onclick="changepic('div2')">
  <img id="div2" />
</div>
```

Comment: why are you naming the id of an `img` tag `div`? ultra confusing

Comment: giving an id to `img` tag and passing the id to the function so that we can find the using `document.getElementById()`.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done easily using requireJS. Define a AMD as page loader, then on button click call that module which will inject the image html as desired.

Check this article
[Lazy Loading of images](http://www.joezimjs.com/javascript/lazy-loading-javascript-with-requirejs/)

Answer (score 0):

If you want, you can, with jQuery, pass the image in data-img argument. So you can pass different image in different div.

HTML

```
<div class="change" data-img="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/1b/Square_200x200.png">
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a0/Circle_-_black_simple.svg" />
</div>
```

jQuery

```
$('.change').click(function(){
    var img=$(this).data('img');
    $(this).children('img').attr('src', img);
});
```

JSFiddle example: https://jsfiddle.net/zwf5k3qw/